# Errors when using the Integral2 function in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, calculus, numerical-integration

As far as I can tell, no one has asked this.
I've been asked to compute the double integral of a function, and also the same double integral but with the order of integration swapped (i.e: first integrate for dydx, then dxdy). Here is my code:

```
    %Define function to be integrated
f = @(x,y) y^2*cos(x);

    %First case. Integration order: dydx
ymin = @(x) cos(x);
I = integral2(f,ymin,1,0,2*pi)

    %Second case. Integration order: dxdy
xmin = @(y) asin(y)+2*pi/2;
xmax = @(y) asin(y)-pi/2;
B = integral2(f,xmin,xmax,-1,1)
```

The error I'm getting is this:

> Error using integral2 (line 71)
>
> XMIN must be a floating point scalar.
>
> Error in EngMathsA1Q1c (line 5)
>
> I = integral2(f,ymin,1,0,2*pi)

I'm sure my mistake is something simple, but I've never used Integral2 before and I'm lost for answers. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the [`integral2` documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/integral2.html), the variable limits are given as the second pair of limits.  So your first integral should be

```
%    Define function to be integrated
f = @(x,y) y.^2.*cos(x);

%    First case. Integration order: dydx
ymin = @(x) cos(x);
I = integral2(f,0,2*pi,ymin,1);
```

The set of constant limits always goes first, **and** Matlab assumes the first argument of `f` is associated with the first set of limits while the second argument of `f` is associated with the second set of limits, which may be a function of the first argument.

---

I point out that second part because if you wish to switch the order of integration, you also need to switch the order of the inputs of `f` accordingly.  Consider the following example:

```
fun = @(x,y) 1./( sqrt(2*x + y) .* (1 + 2*x + y).^2 )
```

A nice little function that is not symmetric in its arguments (i.e., `fun(x,y) ~= fun(y,x)`).  Let's integrate this over an elongated triangle in the first quadrant with vertices at (0,0), (2,0), and (0,1).  Then integrating with `dA == dy dx`, we have

```
>> format('long');
>> ymax = @(x) 1 - x/2;
>> q = integral2(fun,0,2,0,ymax)
q =
   0.220241017339352
```

Cool.  Now let's integrate with `dA == dx dy`:

```
>> xmax = @(y) 2*(1-y);
>> q = integral2(fun,0,1,0,xmax)
q =
   0.241956050772765
```

Oops, that's not equal to the first calculation!  That's because `fun` is defined with `x` as the first argument and `y` as the second, but the previous call to `integral2` is implying that `y` is the first argument to `fun`, and it has constant limits of `0` and `1`.  How do we fix this?  Simply define a new function that flips the arguments:

```
>> fun2 = @(y,x) fun(x,y);
>> q = integral2(fun2,0,1,0,xmax)
q =
   0.220241017706984
```

And all's right with the world. (Although you may notice small differences between the two correct answers due to the error tolerances of `integral2`, which can be adjusted via options per the documentation.)

Answer (score 0):

The error states that you can't pass in a function for the limits of integration. You need to specify a scalar value for each limit of integration. Also, there are some errors in the dimensions/operations of the function. Try this:

```
%Define function to be integrated
f = @(x,y) y.^2.*cos(x);%changed to .^ and .* 

%First case. Integration order: dydx
%ymin = @(x) cos(x);
I = integral2(f,-1,1,0,2*pi)%use scalar values for limits of integration

%Second case. Integration order: dxdy
%xmin = @(y) asin(y)+2*pi/2;
%xmax = @(y) asin(y)-pi/2;
B = integral2(f,0,2*pi,-1,1)% same issue, must use scalars
```